# How find multiple java version in Linux machine

Tags: java

I have installed Java 8 and 11 to my Linux machine. Now I want to find my java 11 version. I used `java -version` command for that.

But i can see always only java 8 version. Can someone please help me to find my java 11 version in machine?

Thank you.

Comment: Check "which java", you will see the full path of the java executable. With good probability, you will find close the jdk 11 installation folder. Take that path instead and run it as "full path/java --version"

Answer (score 1):

below one will list all the installed java versions and will prompt if need to change version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: It  does not show java version like this ```openjdk version "1.8.0_312"```.

Comment: This answer is not universal across all linux distributions